# How to download real images instead of data:image/gif placeholder

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium to scrape a real-estate website. Here's the link - https://www.luxuryestate.com/belgium/brussels-capital-region. I'm getting the actual pictures only for first four images, and for the remaining eleven I'm getting a placeholder pixel like `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`.

If we open this link in the browser, it will have a total of 15 images. Only 4 images are loading. Other images will be loading once we scroll down.

This is the code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
import time
import sys

url = 'https://www.luxuryestate.com/belgium/brussels-capital-region'
chrome_driver_path = './chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

with webdriver as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)

    wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-list")))
    time.sleep(3)
    container = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-list")
    nodes = container.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    print(len(nodes))
    for node in nodes:
        temp = node.find_element_by_tag_name("div")
        wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "loaded")))
        img = temp.find_element_by_tag_name("img")
        img_src= img.get_attribute("src")
        print(img_src)
```

Here's the output:

[image: Please replace this useless image with plain text]

How can I get the actual 15 images, rather than the placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in your question.

> Other images will be loading once we scroll down.

What you can do is, try reaching the end of the page after initial loading with something like following:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

And after this increase the 3-second delay a bit may 5 seconds based on your internet speed.

You'll be able to print all the image links with the current code.

I Suggest not to use forced thread sleep & try managing with WebDriverWait.
But this is the easiest approach based on your current setup.